# Can HCD accommodate all known large cardinal axioms?

Tags: set-theory, lo.logic, large-cardinals, definability

[HOD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinal_definable_set) has been found to be useful in that it is an inner model that can accommodate essentially all known large cardinals.

However, there is a definable well ordering over HOD, so it cannot satisfy large cardinal axioms known to negate choice. On the other hand, there seems to be a hierarchy of [choiceless large cardinals](https://www.jstor.org/stable/26788522) that appears to be highly ordered and amenable to systematic investigation.

Recall [cardinal definable](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/412541/is-every-set-being-cardinal-definable-consistent-with-zf-negation-of-choice) sets, so here we can take the class of all hereditarily cardinal definable sets "HCD", this would be an inner model of ZF.

> Can HCD accommodate ALL known large cardinal axioms?