# Can we define the notion of ordinal\cardinal definable set in Z + Ranks?

Tags: set-theory, lo.logic, definability

Working in [Zermelo + Ranks](https://randall-holmes.github.io/Drafts/hierarchy.pdf), can we define the notions "ordinal definable" set, "[cardinal definable](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/412541/is-every-set-being-cardinal-definable-consistent-with-zf-negation-of-choice)" set? Or does it beg Replacement\Reflection to be defined?

Comment: Can you internalise OD in $V_{\omega+\omega}$?